# how to AOT (ahead-of-time) compile a c++ program

Tags: c++, llvm, jit, clang, aot

I'm new to AOT compilation and I was wondering if someone could post a complete example of how to do a sample "Hello, world!" in c++ using LLVM and clang. I looked on the llvm.org website and cannot find any documentation on how to do AOT compilation using llvm. Basically I'm interested in learning how to do AOT compilation instead of JIT since it is possible to run AOT code on mobile devices.

My question is based on the follow article on compiling actionscript 3 for iphone.

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/logged_in/abansod_iphone.html

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

LLVM is a system meant mostly for JIT compilation rather than AOT.